Is there a way to fix this issue on building a project "Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.0"?
The project doesnt build because of gradle version
`A problem occurred configuring root project 'baked_barbecue'.

Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.0.
Required by:
project :
No matching variant of com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.0 was found. The consumer was configured to find a runtime of a library compatible with Java 8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally, as well as attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '7.5' but:
- Variant 'apiElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.0 declares a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
- Incompatible because this component declares an API of a component compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a runtime of a component compatible with Java 8
- Other compatible attribute:
- Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.5')
- Variant 'javadocElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.0 declares a runtime of a component, and its dependencies declared externally:
- Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
- Other compatible attributes:
- Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
- Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
- Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.5')
- Variant 'runtimeElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.0 declares a runtime of a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
- Incompatible because this component declares a component compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component compatible with Java 8
- Other compatible attribute:
- Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.5')
- Variant 'sourcesElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.0 declares a runtime of a component, and its dependencies declared externally:
- Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
- Other compatible attributes:
- Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
- Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
- Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.5')`

build.gradle
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

        maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }

        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }


    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.amazonaws:aws-devicefarm-gradle-plugin:1.3'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.0'
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:10.3.1"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.14'

        classpath "io.github.jmatsu:license-list-gradle:0.8.1"
       
        classpath 'com.github.ben-manes:gradle-versions-plugin:+'
        // Spotbugs
        classpath "gradle.plugin.com.github.spotbugs.snom:spotbugs-gradle-plugin:4.5.0"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    gradle.projectsEvaluated {
        tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
            //options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
            options.compilerArgs << '-Xlint:unchecked'
            options.compilerArgs << '-Xlint:deprecation'
            //options.compilerArgs << '-Xlint:all'
            options.deprecation = true
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

I tried changing the gradle jdk location, still doesnt work what the ide recommends

Can you share your build.gradle files and also the Android Studio version you are using?

Hello, I added the build.gradle. Im using the latest android studio version jellyfish

It is given in the error logs that your java version(8) is not compatible.
Incompatible because this component declares an API of a component compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a runtime of a component compatible with Java 8
So, you need to check for the compatible versions.
